# How to fix "used by another process" error when editing a text file which was opened using Process.Start()?

Tags: c#, editing, process.start

I' making a console application in c#. I used a `Process.Start()` function to open a text file, which can be edited directly in notepad and program waits for the notepad to close. But when trying to save the file, a warning message pops up saying "File being used by another process".

Since I'm a beginner, I don't know how to fix this problem. I know about `FileAccess`, `FileMode`, `FileStream` but I have never used them and don't think they will help at this point.

This is the constructor before Main() method

```
public AccountApplication()
        {
            Process process = Process.Start("notepad.exe", textFilePath);
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
```

And part of the Main() method where this constructor is used

```
           TextFileWriting:
                AccountApplication openFile;
                Console.Clear();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                Console.Write("Enter a file name: ");
                string filename = Console.ReadLine();
                if (filename == "")
                {
                    goto TextFileWriting;
                }
                textFilePath = Path.Combine(currentUserFolder, filename + ".txt");

                if (File.Exists(textFilePath))
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                    Console.WriteLine("File You specified already has been created. Do you want to overwrite or edit it? (edit/overwrite)");
                    string userAnswer = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (userAnswer == "edit")
                    {
                        openFile = new AccountApplication();
                        goto MainMenu;
                    }
                    else if (userAnswer == "overwrite")
                    {

                        File.CreateText(textFilePath);
                        openFile = new AccountApplication();
                        goto MainMenu;
                    }
                    else if (userAnswer == "")
                    {
                        goto TextFileWriting;
                    }

                }
                else if (!File.Exists(textFilePath))
                {
                    File.CreateText(textFilePath);
                    openFile = new AccountApplication();
                    goto MainMenu;
                }
```

Notepad opened and the program was waiting for it to close. One thing user was unable to do is to save the changes made.

Comment: Most text editors creates a temporary file were the work is done. When you have to save, they create the file based on such temporary file. This allows them to prevent loosing any work done if the file cannot be saved or the program closed unexpectedly. They can recuperate the work from the temp and provide options when the "File being used by another process".

Comment: Notepad does not lock the file, so some other application (yours)? is holding the file open. Notepad can't save the file in that case. Where did the file come from? How was it created?

Comment: BTW, why are you testing for `File.Exists` and `!File.Exists` in the same `if`? If you have concurrency issues, that isn't how to handle them, if not, there is no reason to test again, that is what `if`...`else` means. Why are you calling `new AccountApplication()` multiple times with differing variable names and throwing the result away? That isn't how you should use classes or objects...

Comment: @NetMage First of all, application asks for a user to enter a filename. After that, program checks if the file exists or not. If not, program creates a new file an opens it. `if` and `else` issue was a copy mistake. Now it is corrected. I fixed `new AccountApplication()` calling too. What is the best way to edit the created text file?

Comment: Are you only getting the error when you create a new file? I didn't notice you aren't properly disposing of the return from `File.CreateText`, so you are opening the file and _never closing it_. You need to do `File.CreateText().Close();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line below creates a `StreamWriter` for you:

```
File.CreateText(textFilePath);
```

It is intended to be used like this:

```
using (var writer = File.CreateText(textFilePath))
{
    writer.WriteLine("Hi!");
};
```

If you don't want to write anything to the file, just close the `StreamWriter` immediately:

```
File.CreateText(textFilePath).Close();
```